Did ARPANET hosts have some kind of name resolving before 1974?
I'm trying to complete some information on the history of DNS and name resolution in networking. I've found some information on ARPANET and BBN's protocols relying on the numerical machine code for the 5 bit destination portion of the packets. I then found that host files seemed to have started their use around 1974 to help resolve names to the machine number.
However, in 1971 they also sent the first email with SNDMSG and PBS said they used the email CSX@UCLA. If that's true, did they have some kind of resolving on their hosts that wasn't a host file?
Additionally, the TIP guide from the 1972 conference shows them entering 70 for host #70 and 65 for UCLA. How did they connect with the remote computers before then to teletype to it, did they use the machine number? When did they start to use name resolution?
Edit: Here is some more relevant information I found:

RFC 226, 247, 273, 280, 289, and 384 all relate to what could be considered a "hosts" file. Initially started in RFC 226 by Peggy Karp as Host Mneumonics. There were a few iterations over this through the other RFCs until the Hosts.txt file maintained by Elizabeth in 1974
If we combine this with PBS's claim that Ray's first email using CSX@UCLA, presuming that is correct. That would line up with RFC 226, as in 247 Peggy is already recommending that UCLA use the host name UCLA-7 and UCLA-91. I can't find an exact date yet, but most claim that Ray's email was sent in October of 1971.
I think CYPNET used the same host-to-IMP protocol as any other connection they would have made even after setting up the "Host Mneumonics". It still would be nice to see how CYPNET worked to resolve the name for the terminal to start to package.

Hopefully this is cool for others to read. I'll leave the questions up in case there is more information. Specifically, on the CYPNET protocol

I recently watched a Youtube video produced by RetroBytes regarding the history of the internet.  I can't vouch for his accuracy, but I have no reason to doubt it either.  There is a section relating to DNS that you might find interesting beginning at 20:40.  Here is the link: https://youtu.be/r03AIGRmRAM?si=CCzVCdbA4gE_8_S9&t=1241

I remember back when we had to use bang paths.  Mail addresses looked like host1!host2!...!hostN!user, where host1 was the name of a computer reachable by 1 hop from your computer as listed in your local /etc/hosts.  Similarly, host2 was a computer reachable by 1 hop from host1, and so on to hostN which was your recipient's computer, with user name user.  You had to know the exact route of hops (often 6 or more) from your computer to the recipient.  DNS was a welcome improvement.

@DrSheldon - and having to include the ForwardMail request (too long ago for exact wording) to get through one of the few Bitnet to Arpanet gateways along the way.

@DrSheldon, I thought that bang paths were for hosts that were not connected to Arpanet/Internet. I thought that the "hops" were achieved by UUCP connections. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP#Bang_path I agree that DNS was a big improvement over,... um,... I guess everything that came before, but you couldn't use DNS, until you got connected to the Internet.

So, the Youtube video was almost just a regurgitation of the Wiki page, which helped a little but not exactly what I was looking for. I've come to a point now where I'm pretty certain that the original Teletype system followed the TIP guide from 1972. Now, the SNDMSG program still remains a bit of an enigma. I think the exact thing I'm looking for now is how the CYPNET protocol worked.

I was going to gripe about "Host Mneumonics", but damn, it's actually mangled in the RFC!

Given the assumptions built into old routing techniques and IP-block assignments, and the size of the old ARPANET, it wouldn't suprise me if they didn't see the need for anything more complicated than a hosts file on each machine.  That probably would have encouraged the nesting terminal sessions of early hacker narratives: You connect to the one machine you know the address off and use it's host-file-equivalent to find the next machine to connect to that it knows about.

DEC's internal network managed to handle tens of thousands of nodes using the equivalent of host files. Essentially, every system updated its copy of the database on a nightly basis. I forget the details now but I think a hierarchical distribution was arranged - i.e., you got a copy from a topologically-nearby distribution hub.

@davolfman Yep. And by the 80's, there was a NIC that kept a fairly comprehensive Internet hosts table. I used to download it once a month.

@dave I'd guess YP/NIS but I don't know if the dates align.

@davolfman - not on a DECnet network you don't.  It was basically file copy, a flat file with name/address info, and probably needed OS-specific conversion to the right node database (or maybe you just pumped it into NCP). And being DEC it was surely all glued together with DCL command files.

@dave : Those days were wonderful because they were innocent. It never would have occurred to anyone to have to protect those host files. Anyone could drop a new host into anyone's computer and redirect anything anywhere. None of the office PCs in those days were locked down at night. The wonderfulness of it was, in those days it wasn't necessary. Like locking your door in the community where I grew up.

@JessFuckett - hardly true on VMS or RSX. Replacing the host file needed you to be logged in with a system id.  And in any case, we all worked for the same company. Of course, more security was needed "inside the perimeter", as demonstrated by that (expletive deleted) Kevin Mitnick.

When I worked for DOJ, I walked down to the main justice building on my lunch hour and picketed about Kevin with the 2100 hackers in front of my own department. I was hoping the media would notice my dear DOJ ID, but nobody did. I also took a picture of a free Kevin Sticker on Reno's door, but I never had the nerve to send it to 2100 magazine.

@JessFuckett it wasn't malicious but the amount of shenanigans that used to go on in the university computing labs where I was an undergraduate in the 1990's meant a bit more security would have been welcome :)  One thing that I still laugh about is a PhD colleague who somehow managed to wrangle herself a dedicated Solaris sun station - but never learn that you could run any process on any other machine on the network. So we ran all our jobs on her machine and other than always complaining that it was quite slow she never worked it out.

@DavidWaterworth Wow, that's pretty sh***y. I would hate to find out that  my computer was slow because everybody else was parasitizing it.

@JessFuckett yeah it was a bit, but it wasn't really "her" computer, she just somehow managed to be the only student in the department who managed to get a sun moved to her desk. Everyone else had to use the ones in the lab and they weren't always available.
